# Length of values does not match length of index using np.linspace for pandas

Tags: pandas, for-loop

I am trying to run this code so i can get a chart where the x-axis shows the various values of sigma and y-axis shows the various values of profit

```
def price(cost,sigma):
    return cost*sigma
def profit(cost,sigma,expected_loss):
    return[(sigma-1)*cost-expected_loss]
sigmas=np.linspace(1,1000,endpoint=True,retstep=False,dtype=None,axis=0)
plt.figure()
for sigma in sigmas:
    df['profit']=profit(df['cost'],sigma,df['expected_loss'])
    df['i_price']=price(df['cost'],sigma)
    sum_profit=df.loc[df['risk_premium']>df['i_price'],'profit'].sum()
    plt.plot(sigma,sum_profit,color='green',marker='o',linestyle='solid')
plt.xlabel('sigma')
plt.ylabel('sum_profit')
plt.show()'
```